# I paste a text copied into a csv file?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How do I paste a text copied into a variable (text), at each restart of my program in a CSV file?
I use Python and have created a blank CSV file with Excel

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what you mean.

Comment: @lolino can you please elaborate? do you just wish to paste the content from clipboard to your csv file? what is a script cycle?

Comment: @ shripal mehta yes, every time the program terminates, I copy an element into a variable (text) and after that I would like to paste into a cvs file. The element is a word that always changes each time the program is restarted. I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it's a bit abstractive but with main idea:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
delimeter = ';'
with open('file.csv', 'w+') as _file:
    _l = ['your', 'header', 'columns', 'names']
    _file.write(delimeter.join(_l))
    for site in [your sites list]:

        driver.get(site)
        time.sleep(1)
        
        your_selenium script

        all_elements = [""]
        _str = delimeter.join(all_elements)
        _file.write(_str)

driver.close()
```

Comment: if it's a csv, delimiter should be `,` unless it's used a generalisation for delimited files

Comment: @shripalmehta it can be any delimiter, like I said, it's abstractive code snipped, with main goal

Comment: @Vova every time the program terminates, I copy an element into a variable (text) and after that I would like to paste into a cvs file. The element is a word that always changes each time the program is restarted.

Comment: again, it's just abstraction, you can put not an element, text might be, or text from the page, like element.text

Comment: @lolino show us your code and url where you would like to get text